# Run multiple Data fusion replication jobs on one dataproc cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, change-data-capture

I am currently analyzing GCP data fusion replication features to ingest initial snapshot followed by the CDC.

The plan is to create one replication job per table because adding a new table is not supported once the replication job is created. I tried to a table by deleting and creating the replication job with same name. But it results the initial snapshot load for the other tables as well.

Having said that, in order to overcome the above 2 scenarios, I am planning to create replication job per table. However, every replication job creates its own dataproc cluster which will incur more costs.

Is it possible to run all replication jobs on one dataproc autoscaling cluster?
Note: The instance type is Basic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Reusing the cluster is possible https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/1683390465/Reusing+Dataproc+clusters,
This will mark your already provisioned cluster as reusable at the end of the job, and will just save you provisioning time of dataproc cluster (approx. 90 - 150 sec) for every run.

Not sure if multiple data fusion jobs can be summited to same cluster parallelly, which I am looking for :)